# Solve matrix differential equation using a substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve
$$t \frac{\mathrm{d} \mathbf{x}}{\mathrm{d} t}=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 2\\ 
1 & 3
\end{pmatrix} \mathbf{x} ~~,~~\mathbf{x}(1)=\begin{pmatrix}
2\\ 
3
\end{pmatrix}$$
using the substitution $t=e^u$, $\mathbf{y}(u)=\mathbf{x}(e^u)$. I tried substituting

$$\frac{\mathrm{d} \mathbf{x}(e^{u(t)})}{\mathrm{d} t}=\frac{\mathrm{d} \mathbf{x}}{\mathrm{d} t}e^u \frac{\mathrm{d} u}{\mathrm{d} t}=\frac{\mathrm{d} \mathbf{x}}{\mathrm{d} t}e^u \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t}(\ln t)=\frac{1}{t}\frac{\mathrm{d} \mathbf{x}}{\mathrm{d} t}e^u$$
 and I fail to understand how does it help solving the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: @Moo - yes. Why?

Comment: @Moo - textbook on differential equations. It simply gives the initial value problem and asks to solve it using this substitution.

Comment: Note that, for scalar $x$, you have $$
t\frac{{d\,x}}
{{d\,t}} = k\;x\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \frac{{d\,x}}
{x} = k\frac{{d\,t}}
{t}\quad  \Rightarrow \quad x = c\,t^{\,k} 
$$
so your substitution is not right, because of the multiplying $t$, and you shall substitute with a combination of the above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how in works on the scalar equation:

Let $tx'=kx$ and let $t=e^u$.

Then
$$
x(t)=x(e^{u})=y(u)=y(\log t).
$$

Now
$$
\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{dy}{du}\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{1}{t}y'.
$$

hence your equation becomes $y'=ky$, which is easy to solve. Do the same for your matrix notation.